# how ObjectMapper class methods works internally like readvalue() and writevalue()

Tags: java, rest, web-services

how ObjectMapper class methods works internally like read value() and write value()
my question is that I want to convert JSON object into java object with the help of object mapper with method read value but I want to know how to read value works internally

Comment: That's too broad to be answered here. Please read the source code and javadocs

Comment: Read the chapter on reflection in java. It basically uses reflection to read and write values.

Comment: also heavily depends on the version you want to use

Answer (score 0):

student.json

`{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Poornima",
  "age": 18,
  "standard": "XI",
  "address": {
    "street": "Main Street",
    "city": "Chelsea",
    "zipcode": 20571
  },
  "courses": [
    "Science",
    "Physical Education"
  ]
}`

Take the example of preceding nested JSON object. It consist of JSON Object and a JSON Array within a JSON Object.Based on the JSON data, we’ll create two POJOs: Courses and Students.

Internally When ObjectMapper maps JSON to POJOs, it inspects the setter methods. ObjectMapper by default maps a key for the JSON field with the setter method name. For Example, ObjectMapper will map the name JSON field with the setName() setter method in a POJO.

For more info you can refer following link

[https://dzone.com/articles/processing-json-with-jackson](http://%20https://dzone.com/articles/processing-json-with-jackson)